# reading unicode text from assets

Tags: android, unicode, file-io

Trying to read an utf-8 encoded file in android...

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(assets.open("data.txt"), "UTF-8");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader); 
String line;
//The line below throws an IOException!!
line = br.readLine();
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: The code looks o.k. can you provide detailed error output? Also I do not think you need to specify UTF-8 encoding since that's default.

Comment: android debugging log shows this: D/asset <1183>: Data exceeds UNCOMPRESS_DATA_MAX (2099900 vs 1048576)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you file is too big, you have to split it onto several files (1048576 bytes maximum for each) or find another way to reduce file size. Here is an article about similar problem http://androidgps.blogspot.com/2008/10/dealing-with-large-resources.html